# ZendFramework set environment using htaccess failing?

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, environment-variables, ini

this is the **.htaccess** file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks 
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

this is **application.ini**

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

and this is index.php

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

    echo APPLICATION_ENV; exit;
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

I have seen that `mod_rewrite` is enabled in apache is there anything I am missing in application.ini or somewhere in zend i have searched all related questions in form and none have worked for me anybody please help.

Comment: Could you show us the index.php file? That is the place where the application environment is usually defined.

Comment: i have icluded the index.php when iam printing Application_env it is showing as production

Comment: Are you sure that Apache's mod_env is enabled? And could you show the output of `getenv('APPLICATION_ENV')`?

Comment: yes its enabled,and when i print getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') blank screen is comming i.e its not set

Comment: "AllowOverride" set to all in server config?

Comment: i have tried that also no result

Comment: add "RewriteBase /" after "rewrite engine on"

Comment: that also not working @Tarika

Comment: Try replacing the first 2 conditions with this one: `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f` without `OR`. It is not needed.

Comment: It'd be worth debugging this a little - if you add `var_dump(getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'));exit;` at the top of your index.php what do you see? Also are you using mod_php or fcgi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use **SetEnv** within an .htaccess file, You have to define:

**AllowOverride FileInfo**

or

**AllowOverride All**

In your apache **httpd.conf** (within the relevant **virtual host** directory block)

Then restart apache